# Spark / Scala: Split row into several rows based on value change in current row

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Using Databricks, Spark 3.0.1

To use the legacy format, I have set: `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy","LEGACY")`

I have a dataframe similar to the sample below.

Each row needs to be split in several rows based on a change in consecutive values. The other columns can be filled with null.

**Sample**:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|id  |t.n1|t.n2|t.n3|t.n4|t.n5|t.n6|t.n7|t.n8|t.n9|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|1   |100 |100 |100 |500 |500 |500 |200 |200 |200 |
|2   |100 |100 |700 |700 |700 |100 |100 |100 |100 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

**Expected Output:**

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+   
|id  |t.n1|t.n2|t.n3|t.n4|t.n5|t.n6|t.n7|t.n8|t.n9|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|1   |100 |100 |100 |Nan |Nan |Nan |Nan |Nan |Nan |
|2   |Nan |Nan |Nan |500 |500 |500 |Nan |Nan |Nan |
|3   |Nan |Nan |Nan |Nan |Nan |Nan |200 |200 |200 |
|4   |100 |100 |Nan |Nan |Nan |Nan |Nan |Nan |Nan |
|5   |Nan |Nan |700 |700 |700 |Nan |Nan |Nan |Nan |
|6   |Nan |Nan |Nan |Nan |Nan |100 |100 |100 |100 |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224730/discussion-on-question-by-yamhiro-spark-scala-split-row-in-several-rows-based).

Comment: have you tested my solution, does it fit you? If yes, please consider to accept

Comment: disappointed no upvote for my solution which also works

Comment: Hi @thebluephantom,
thanks for your time in solving this issue. It must be my fault since I wasn't able to make your solution work (I simply couldn't get to transform my Dataframe to dataset/RDD without getting an error). I didn't know I could upvote besides accepting an answer. just did it !

Comment: Interesting no issues here

Comment: I have to say it is for me one of the most learnsome questions. I solved it with 3Gl and RR indeed had a more elegant solution, but I had took at it and trace to get the gist of it. I assume it was clear to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given this dataframe :

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| id| n1| n2| n3| n4| n5| n6| n7| n8| n9|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  1|100|100|100|500|500|500|200|200|200|
|  2|100|100|700|700|700|100|100|100|100|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

I came up with a solution based in a mixture between dataframes and datasets:

```
val l = 9 // number of cols
df
  // put values into array
  .select($"id", array(df.columns.tail.map(col): _*).as("col"))
  // switch to dataset api
  .as[(Int, Seq[Int])]
  .flatMap { case (id, arr) => {
    val arrI = arr.zipWithIndex
    // split list in sublist based on adjacent values
    arrI.tail
      .foldLeft(Seq(Seq(arrI.head)))((acc, curr) =>
        if (acc.last.last._1 == curr._1) {
          acc.init :+ (acc.last :+ curr)
        } else {
          acc :+ Seq(curr)
        }
      )
     // aggregate sublists into value, from, to
      .map(chunk => (chunk.head._1, chunk.map(_._2).min, chunk.map(_._2).max))
      // generate new lists, fill with Nones
      .zipWithIndex
      .map { case ((num, from, to),subI) => (id,subI+1,(0 until l).map(i=> if(i>=from && i<=to) Some(num) else None))}
  }
  }
  .toDF("id","sub_id","values") // back to dataframe api
  // rename columns
  .select($"id"+:$"sub_id"+:(0 until l).map(i => $"values"(i).as(s"n${i+1}")):_*)
  .show(false)
```

which yields:

```
+---+------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|id |sub_id|n1  |n2  |n3  |n4  |n5  |n6  |n7  |n8  |n9  |
+---+------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|1  |1     |100 |100 |100 |null|null|null|null|null|null|
|1  |2     |null|null|null|500 |500 |500 |null|null|null|
|1  |3     |null|null|null|null|null|null|200 |200 |200 |
|2  |1     |100 |100 |null|null|null|null|null|null|null|
|2  |2     |null|null|700 |700 |700 |null|null|null|null|
|2  |3     |null|null|null|null|null|100 |100 |100 |100 |
+---+------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

As you can see I was not yet successful to get the correct id, this would need some more work. The problem is to make a subsequent id, this would need a wide transformation (window-function without partitioning) which would lead to a performance-bottleneck

Comment: think mine is easier to understand, but looks good.

Comment: Good Solution.. :)

Comment: @thebluephantom I did not remove he comment, no idea why it disappeared

Comment: @thebluephantom, I have removed my previous the comment / replaced that with this -  "Good Solution" & upvoted both solution.

Comment: @thebluephantom , is above comments are related to my previous comment or any other comments which are removed ?

Answer (score 1):

> Some good old-fashioned coding. Along with a few learnable items for Scala.
>
> Invariably the Any aspects reared its ugly head so I used Option approach. Note toString() required and a particular way of building List dynamically.
>
> Is it functional programming? Less so than the other solution, but was not sure how to do with fold, etc. with nested structures. Intermediate solution this then, that may serve yu well with mapPartitions.

Here is the code:

```
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import scala.util.Try

def tryToInt( s: String ) = Try(s.toInt).toOption 
def lp( a: List[Int] ) :List[List[Option[Int]]] = {
      var cnt:Int = 0
      var tempAA: List[List[Int]] = List()
      var tempA: List[Int] = List()
      var c:Int = 0
      val sInput = a.size
      // Does not work for empty List, but will not be empty
      for (v <- a) {
                    if (cnt > 0 ) { if (v != c) 
                                       { tempAA = tempAA :+ tempA
                                         tempA = List()
                                  }
                    } 
                    c = v
                    cnt +=1
                    tempA = tempA :+ v 
      }
      tempAA = tempAA :+ tempA

      val numItems = tempAA.map(x => x.size)          // List of occurrences per slot 
      val cumCount = numItems.scanLeft(0)(_ + _).tail // Cumulative count
      var res: List[List[Option[Int]]] = List()
      var tempAAA: List[List[String]] = List()
   
      for (i <- 0 until numItems.length) {
            val itemsLeft = cumCount(i) - numItems(i)
            val itemsRight = sInput - cumCount(i)
            val left = List.fill(itemsLeft)(None)
            val right = List.fill(itemsRight)(None)
        
            tempAAA = List()
            tempAAA = tempAAA :+ left.map(_.toString())
            tempAAA = tempAAA :+ tempAA(i).map(_.toString())
            tempAAA = tempAAA :+ right.map(_.toString())
            val tempAAAA = tempAAA.flatten.map(_.toString()).map(x => tryToInt(x))
            res = res :+ tempAAAA
      }
      return res
}

val dataIn = Seq((1,2,2,3,5,5,5,5,5), (4,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,5), (5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5)).toDS()
val data = dataIn.withColumn("input", array(dataIn.columns.map(col): _*)).select($"input").as[List[Int]]
val df = data.rdd.map(lp).toDF().select(explode($"value"))
val n = dataIn.columns.size
df.select( (0 until n).map(i => col("col")(i).alias(s"c${i+1}")): _*).show(false)
```

returns:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|c1  |c2  |c3  |c4  |c5  |c6  |c7  |c8  |c9  |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|1   |null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|
|null|2   |2   |null|null|null|null|null|null|
|null|null|null|3   |null|null|null|null|null|
|null|null|null|null|5   |5   |5   |5   |5   |
|4   |null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|
|null|2   |2   |2   |null|null|null|null|null|
|null|null|null|null|5   |5   |5   |5   |5   |
|5   |5   |5   |5   |5   |5   |5   |5   |5   |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Wow. That looks impressive. I will check if it works on my case. As silly as it sounds, currently struggling to transform my current dataframe to a rdd/dataset.  I have tried with Encoders or by loading it directly as a rdd, but none seems to work. I will give it a try again tomorrow first thing in the morning.

In any case, Thanks for the time spent on it!

Comment: it is an interesting data wrangling question, it works. u have to add a few things.

Comment: Does your solution handle missing values? If that's the case, I guess your solution is better then

Comment: unclear what outcome would be as u did not specify that